# AngularJS pre-render with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, angularjs

Is there any way that we can pre render angularJS template in rails and then send only html to client ?

I want to solve the real problem with SEO, even if we have an alternative way to use `<noscript>`

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 1):

I've read in several places about using PhantomJS to render the site on the server and save the result as static HTML.

[PhantomJS for Server-side rendering](http://thedigitalself.com/blog/seo-and-javascript-with-phantomjs-server-side-rendering)

Comment: Thanks @Brian, I've taken a look at that solution since it's really not my taste :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this rails middle ware [pre-render rails](https://github.com/prerender/prerender_rails)